# for-loop not working with empty dataframe in python

Tags: python

I have a python df:

```
    def foo():
        s1 = pd.DataFrame({'A' : []})
        s2 = pd.DataFrame({'B' : [2]})
        s3 = pd.DataFrame({'C' : [3]})
        return s1, s2, s3

    s1, s2, s3 = foo()
```

s1 is empty, s2 returns 2 and s3 returns 3.

I wrote this for-loop:

```
    s = [s1, s2, s3]
    for i in s:
       if i.empty:
         print(i + "the result is null")
       else:
         print(i + "the result is not null")
```

but this is not doing what I want:

```
    s1 the result is null
    s2 the result is not null
    s3 the result is not null
```

any suggestions???

Comment: What is the issue, exactly? Are you not familiar with dictionaries and lists?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You lose the names once you put them in a list..

How about this:

```
s = {'s1':s1,'s2':s2,'s3':s3}
for i in s.keys():
    if s[i].empty:
        print(i + " the result is null")
    else:
        print(i + " the result is not null")
```

Answer (score 0):

s1, s2, and s3 are simply names which reference particular DataFrame objects, but not a part of the objects themselves and thus not available to print.

The following will print the name of the first key instead:

```
for i in s:
    if i.empty:
        print(i.keys()[0] + " the result is null")
    else:
        print(i .keys()[0] + " the result is not null")
```

giving,

```
A the result is null
B the result is not null
C the result is not null
```

Or, you could store the name in the DataFrame itself.